# font awesome only changes font-size in html, not css

Tags: css, font-awesome

```
<i class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 50px;"></i>
```

works

```
.fa-graduation-cap {
margin-top: 38px;
color: #E46A6B;
font-size: 50px;
}
```

doesnt work

I've never had this issue before. Any idea?

Yes, I do have the font-awesome css correctly linked.

Comment: can u show us live ex or url so we can have a look

Comment: also check by inspect element whats the issue

Comment: There are soo many things wrong with that title..

Comment: you try adding important to the style

Comment: !important fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the font-size is already defined for the icons in the `font-awesome.css` file. Adding the style tag to the html code overrides these predefined classes. Try typing `!important` after defining font-size in the css to explicitly override. For example:

```
.fa-graduation-cap {
  margin-top: 38px;
  color: #E46A6B;
  font-size: 50px !important;
}
```

Like @developernator stated, you can also use the predefined classes. However, I find that most of the time the right size falls between the sizes of these classes.

Answer (score 1):

The class uses first inline css then internal css and then external css

Your font awesome might have already given inline css either remove inline css or
do-

`font-size: 50px !important;`